# Login popup vs lightbox in Facebook canvas app

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-canvas

I have a Facebook canvas app, which calls `FB.getAuthResponse()` first and, if necessary, `FB.login()`. The documentation of the JS SDK clearly states `FB.login()` opens a login popup window, which is correct when I hit the canvas URL directly. However, when I do the same thing in the canvas page as an anonymous user a "Not logged in" lightbox appears and redirects to the login page.

Is there any way of unifying this behaviour (preferably always using popup)?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's possible to explicitly specify the 'format' of the login window when using JS SDK - [`FB.login()` accepts the `display` parameter](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/) which defines the display mode of a window.

The final code looks like this:

```
var authResponse = FB.getAuthResponse();
if (authResponse && authResponse.signedRequest) {
    addFieldsAndSubmit(authResponse.signedRequest);
} else {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response && response.authResponse) {
            addFieldsAndSubmit(response.authResponse.signedRequest);
        }
    }, {scope:'email', display: 'popup'});
}
```